# Tango Project LoadADF and render object in Rajawali3D surface

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I am trying to load the latest ADF and Localize it.If the text is localized then it would be displayed in a textView.
If it is localized then on clicking save button editText would appear and the text of button will be changed to "save Object" on clicking that the text entered would be toasted.
I am using Rajawali 3D surface view to render the Video.
But on running it My screen is black only textView and button are shown.
Localization TextView is also blank.

Here is my MainActivity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final double UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS = 100.0;

private final Object mSharedLock = new Object();
// private static final String sTimestampFormat = "Timestamp: %f";
private static final int SECS_TO_MILLISECS = 1000;
private double mPreviousPoseTimeStamp;
private double mTimeToNextUpdate = UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS;
private TextView mUuidTextView;
private TextView mRelocalizationTextView;
private boolean mIsRelocalized;
private EditText mObjectValueEditText;
private Button mSaveButton;
private boolean mIsLocationSave = false;
private boolean mIsSavePoseData = false;
private static final int INVALID_TEXTURE_ID = 0;
private RajawaliSurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private VideoRenderer mRenderer;

// For all current Tango devices, color camera is in the camera id 0.
private static final int COLOR_CAMERA_ID = 0;

private TangoCameraIntrinsics mIntrinsics;
private Tango mTango;
private TangoConfig mConfig;
private boolean mIsConnected = false;
private double mCameraPoseTimestamp = 0;

// NOTE: Naming indicates which thread is in charge of updating this variable
private int mConnectedTextureIdGlThread = INVALID_TEXTURE_ID;
private AtomicBoolean mIsFrameAvailableTangoThread = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private double mRgbTimestampGlThread;

private int mColorCameraToDisplayAndroidRotation = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startActivityForResult(
            Tango.getRequestPermissionIntent(Tango.PERMISSIONTYPE_ADF_LOAD_SAVE),
            Tango.TANGO_INTENT_ACTIVITYCODE);
    mSurfaceView = (RajawaliSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    mObjectValueEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location_edittext);
    mSaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    mRenderer = new VideoRenderer(this);
    onClickSaveButton();
    // Set-up a dummy OpenGL renderer associated with this surface view
    DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    if (displayManager != null) {
        displayManager.registerDisplayListener(new DisplayManager.DisplayListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDisplayAdded(int displayId) {}

            @Override
            public void onDisplayChanged(int displayId) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Camera.CameraInfo colorCameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                    Camera.getCameraInfo(COLOR_CAMERA_ID, colorCameraInfo);

                    mColorCameraToDisplayAndroidRotation =
                            getColorCameraToDisplayAndroidRotation(display.getRotation(),
                                    colorCameraInfo.orientation);
                    mRenderer.updateColorCameraTextureUv(mColorCameraToDisplayAndroidRotation);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisplayRemoved(int displayId) {}
        }, null);
    }

    setupRenderer();
}

private void onClickSaveButton() {
    mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mIsLocationSave == false) {
                mIsLocationSave = true;
                mObjectValueEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSaveButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.save_object));
            } else {
                mIsLocationSave = false;
                String text=mObjectValueEditText.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mObjectValueEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //TODO:Add helper logic
                mIsSavePoseData=true;
                mSaveButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.save));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSurfaceView.onResume();
    // Set render mode to RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY to force getting onDraw callbacks until the
    // Tango service is properly set-up and we start getting onFrameAvailable callbacks.
    mSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

    // Initialize Tango Service as a normal Android Service, since we call mTango.disconnect()
    // in onPause, this will unbind Tango Service, so every time when onResume gets called, we
    // should create a new Tango object.
    mTango = new Tango(MainActivity.this, new Runnable() {
        // Pass in a Runnable to be called from UI thread when Tango is ready, this Runnable
        // will be running on a new thread.
        // When Tango is ready, we can call Tango functions safely here only when there is no UI
        // thread changes involved.
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Synchronize against disconnecting while the service is being used in
            // the OpenGL thread or in the UI thread.
            synchronized (MainActivity.this) {
                try {
                    TangoSupport.initialize();
                    mConfig = setupTangoConfig(mTango);
                    mTango.connect(mConfig);
                    startupTango();
                    mIsConnected = true;
                } catch (TangoOutOfDateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_out_of_date), e);
                } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_error), e);
                } catch (TangoInvalidException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_invalid), e);
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        synchronized (MainActivity.this) {
                            setupTextViewsAndButtons(mTango, true,
                                    true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSurfaceView.onPause();
    mIsRelocalized = false;
    // Synchronize against disconnecting while the service is being used in the OpenGL
    // thread or in the UI thread.
    // NOTE: DO NOT lock against this same object in the Tango callback thread.
    // Tango.disconnect will block here until all Tango callback calls are finished.
    // If you lock against this object in a Tango callback thread it will cause a deadlock.
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            mIsConnected = false;
            mTango.disconnectCamera(TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
            // We need to invalidate the connected texture ID so that we cause a
            // re-connection in the OpenGL thread after resume
            mConnectedTextureIdGlThread = INVALID_TEXTURE_ID;
            mTango.disconnect();
            mIsConnected = false;
        } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_error), e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Sets up the tango configuration object. Make sure mTango object is initialized before
 * making this call.
 */
private TangoConfig setupTangoConfig(Tango tango) {
    // Create a new Tango Configuration and enable the Camera API
    TangoConfig config = tango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORCAMERA, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DRIFT_CORRECTION, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_LOWLATENCYIMUINTEGRATION, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_LEARNINGMODE, false);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_MOTIONTRACKING, true);
    // Tango service should automatically attempt to recover when it enters an invalid state.
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_AUTORECOVERY, true);

    // Check for Load ADF/Constant Space relocalization mode.

    ArrayList<String> fullUuidList;
    // Returns a list of ADFs with their UUIDs.
    fullUuidList = tango.listAreaDescriptions();
    // Load the latest ADF if ADFs are found.
    if (fullUuidList.size() > 0) {
        config.putString(TangoConfig.KEY_STRING_AREADESCRIPTION,
                fullUuidList.get(fullUuidList.size() - 1));
    }

    return config;
}

/**
 * Set up the callback listeners for the Tango service and obtain other parameters required
 * after Tango connection.
 * Listen to updates from the RGB camera.
 */
private void startupTango() {
    // Lock configuration and connect to Tango
    // Select coordinate frame pair
    ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> framePairs = new ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair>();
    framePairs.add(new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE,
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE));
    framePairs.add(new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION,
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE));
    framePairs.add(new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION,
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE));


    // Listen for new Tango data
    mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new Tango.OnTangoUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPoseAvailable(final TangoPoseData pose) {
            // Make sure to have atomic access to Tango Data so that UI loop doesn't interfere
            // while Pose call back is updating the data.
            synchronized (mSharedLock) {
                // Check for Device wrt ADF pose, Device wrt Start of Service pose, Start of
                // Service wrt ADF pose (This pose determines if the device is relocalized or
                // not).
                if (pose.baseFrame == TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION
                        && pose.targetFrame == TangoPoseData
                        .COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE) {
                    if (pose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_VALID) {
                        mIsRelocalized = true;
                    } else {
                        mIsRelocalized = false;
                    }

                }

                if (mIsSavePoseData&&mIsRelocalized) {
                    mIsSavePoseData=false;
                    float [] traslations=pose.getTranslationAsFloats();
                    Log.i("translation",traslations[0]+" "+traslations[1]+" "+traslations[2]);

                }

            }

            final double deltaTime = (pose.timestamp - mPreviousPoseTimeStamp) *
                    SECS_TO_MILLISECS;
            mPreviousPoseTimeStamp = pose.timestamp;
            mTimeToNextUpdate -= deltaTime;

            if (mTimeToNextUpdate < 0.0) {
                mTimeToNextUpdate = UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        synchronized (mSharedLock) {
                            mRelocalizationTextView.setText(mIsRelocalized ?
                                    getString(R.string.localized) :
                                    getString(R.string.not_localized));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        //Deprecated method
        @Override
        public void onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData xyzIj) {
            // We are not using onXyzIjAvailable for this app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onPointCloudAvailable(final TangoPointCloudData pointCloudData) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTangoEvent(final TangoEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraId) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFrameAvailable");

            if (cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR) {
                // Now that we are receiving onFrameAvailable callbacks, we can switch
                // to RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY to drive the render loop from this callback.
                // This will result on a frame rate of  approximately 30FPS, in synchrony with
                // the RGB camera driver.
                // If you need to render at a higher rate (i.e.: if you want to render complex
                // animations smoothly) you  can use RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY throughout the
                // application lifecycle.
                if (mSurfaceView.getRenderMode() != GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY) {
                    mSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
                }

                mSurfaceView.requestRender();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Sets Texts views to display statistics of Poses being received. This also sets the buttons
 * used in the UI. Please note that this needs to be called after TangoService and Config
 * objects are initialized since we use them for the SDK related stuff like version number
 * etc.
 */
private void setupTextViewsAndButtons(Tango tango, boolean isLearningMode, boolean isLoadAdf) {
    mRelocalizationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.relocalization_textview);
    mUuidTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adf_uuid_textview);

    if (isLoadAdf) {
        ArrayList<String> fullUuidList;
        // Returns a list of ADFs with their UUIDs
        fullUuidList = tango.listAreaDescriptions();
        if (fullUuidList.size() == 0) {
            mUuidTextView.setText(R.string.no_uuid);
        } else {
            mUuidTextView.setText(getString(R.string.number_of_adfs) + fullUuidList.size()
                    + getString(R.string.latest_adf_is)
                    + fullUuidList.get(fullUuidList.size() - 1));
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Here is where you would set-up your rendering logic. We're replacing it with a minimalistic,
 * dummy example using a standard GLSurfaceView and a basic renderer, for illustration purposes
 * only.
 */
private void setupRenderer() {

    mRenderer.getCurrentScene().registerFrameCallback(new ASceneFrameCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPreFrame(long sceneTime, double deltaTime) {

            // into the scene.

            // Prevent concurrent access to {@code mIsFrameAvailableTangoThread} from the Tango
            // callback thread and service disconnection from an onPause event.
            try {
                synchronized (MainActivity.this) {
                    // Don't execute any tango API actions if we're not connected to the service
                    if (!mIsConnected) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Set-up scene camera projection to match RGB camera intrinsics.
                    if (!mRenderer.isSceneCameraConfigured()) {
                        mRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(
                                projectionMatrixFromCameraIntrinsics(mIntrinsics,
                                        mColorCameraToDisplayAndroidRotation));
                    }
                    // Connect the camera texture to the OpenGL Texture if necessary
                    // NOTE: When the OpenGL context is recycled, Rajawali may re-generate the
                    // texture with a different ID.
                    if (mConnectedTextureIdGlThread != mRenderer.getTextureId()) {
                        mTango.connectTextureId(TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR,
                                mRenderer.getTextureId());
                        mConnectedTextureIdGlThread = mRenderer.getTextureId();
                        Log.d(TAG, "connected to texture id: " + mRenderer.getTextureId());
                    }
                    if (mIsFrameAvailableTangoThread.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                        mRgbTimestampGlThread =
                                mTango.updateTexture(TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
                    }

                    // If a new RGB frame has been rendered, update the camera pose to match.
                    if (mRgbTimestampGlThread > mCameraPoseTimestamp) {
                        // Calculate the camera color pose at the camera frame update time in
                        // OpenGL engine.
                        //
                        // When drift correction mode is enabled in config file, we must query
                        // the device with respect to Area Description pose in order to use the
                        // drift corrected pose.
                        //
                        // Note that if you don't want to use the drift corrected pose, the
                        // normal device with respect to start of service pose is available.
                        TangoPoseData lastFramePose = TangoSupport.getPoseAtTime(
                                mRgbTimestampGlThread,
                                TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION,
                                TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR,
                                TangoSupport.TANGO_SUPPORT_ENGINE_OPENGL,
                                mColorCameraToDisplayAndroidRotation);
                        if (lastFramePose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_VALID) {
                            // Update the camera pose from the renderer
                            mRenderer.updateRenderCameraPose(lastFramePose);
                            mCameraPoseTimestamp = lastFramePose.timestamp;
                        } else {
                            // When the pose status is not valid, it indicates the tracking has
                            // been lost. In this case, we simply stop rendering.
                            //
                            // This is also the place to display UI to suggest the user walk
                            // to recover tracking.
                            Log.w(TAG, "Can't get device pose at time: " +
                                    mRgbTimestampGlThread);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Avoid crashing the application due to unhandled exceptions
            } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Tango API call error within the OpenGL render thread", e);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception on the OpenGL thread", t);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreDraw(long sceneTime, double deltaTime) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPostFrame(long sceneTime, double deltaTime) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean callPreFrame() {
            return true;
        }
    });

    mSurfaceView.setSurfaceRenderer(mRenderer);

}

private static int getColorCameraToDisplayAndroidRotation(int displayRotation,
                                                          int cameraRotation) {
    int cameraRotationNormalized = 0;
    switch (cameraRotation) {
        case 90:
            cameraRotationNormalized = 1;
            break;
        case 180:
            cameraRotationNormalized = 2;
            break;
        case 270:
            cameraRotationNormalized = 3;
            break;
        default:
            cameraRotationNormalized = 0;
            break;
    }
    int ret = displayRotation - cameraRotationNormalized;
    if (ret < 0) {
        ret += 4;
    }
    return ret;
}

/**
 * Use Tango camera intrinsics to calculate the projection Matrix for the Rajawali scene.

private static float[] projectionMatrixFromCameraIntrinsics(TangoCameraIntrinsics intrinsics,
                                                            int rotation) {
    // Adjust camera intrinsics according to rotation
    float cx = (float) intrinsics.cx;
    float cy = (float) intrinsics.cy;
    float width = (float) intrinsics.width;
    float height = (float) intrinsics.height;
    float fx = (float) intrinsics.fx;
    float fy = (float) intrinsics.fy;

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            cx = (float) intrinsics.cy;
            cy = (float) intrinsics.width - (float) intrinsics.cx;
            width = (float) intrinsics.height;
            height = (float) intrinsics.width;
            fx = (float) intrinsics.fy;
            fy = (float) intrinsics.fx;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            cx = (float) intrinsics.width - cx;
            cy = (float) intrinsics.height - cy;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            cx = (float) intrinsics.height - (float) intrinsics.cy;
            cy = (float) intrinsics.cx;
            width = (float) intrinsics.height;
            height = (float) intrinsics.width;
            fx = (float) intrinsics.fy;
            fy = (float) intrinsics.fx;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Uses frustumM to create a projection matrix taking into account calibrated camera
    // intrinsic parameter.
    // Reference: http://ksimek.github.io/2013/06/03/calibrated_cameras_in_opengl/
    float near = 0.1f;
    float far = 100;

    float xScale = near / fx;
    float yScale = near / fy;
    float xOffset = (cx - (width / 2.0f)) * xScale;
    // Color camera's coordinates has y pointing downwards so we negate this term.
    float yOffset = -(cy - (height / 2.0f)) * yScale;

    float m[] = new float[16];
    Matrix.frustumM(m, 0,
            xScale * (float) -width / 2.0f - xOffset,
            xScale * (float) width / 2.0f - xOffset,
            yScale * (float) -height / 2.0f - yOffset,
            yScale * (float) height / 2.0f - yOffset,
            near, far);
    return m;
}
```

}

VideoRender.java Code

//Extending RajawaliSurface View

```
/**
 * Renderer that implements a basic augmented reality scene using Rajawali.
 * It creates a scene with a background quad taking the whole screen, where     the color camera is
 */
public class VideoRenderer extends RajawaliRenderer {
    private static final String TAG = VideoRenderer.class.getSimpleName();

private float[] textureCoords0 = new float[]{0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F};
private float[] textureCoords270 = new float[]{0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F};
private float[] textureCoords180 = new float[]{1.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F};
private float[] textureCoords90 = new float[]{1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F};

// Rajawali texture used to render the Tango color camera.
private ATexture mTangoCameraTexture;

// Keeps track of whether the scene camera has been configured.
private boolean mSceneCameraConfigured;

private ScreenQuad mBackgroundQuad = new ScreenQuad();

public VideoRenderer(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void initScene() {
    // Create a quad covering the whole background and assign a texture to it where the
    // Tango color camera contents will be rendered.
    Material tangoCameraMaterial = new Material();
    tangoCameraMaterial.setColorInfluence(0);

    mBackgroundQuad.getGeometry().setTextureCoords(textureCoords0);
    // We need to use Rajawali's {@code StreamingTexture} since it sets up the texture
    // for GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES rendering
    mTangoCameraTexture =
            new StreamingTexture("camera", (StreamingTexture.ISurfaceListener) null);
    try {
        tangoCameraMaterial.addTexture(mTangoCameraTexture);
        mBackgroundQuad.setMaterial(tangoCameraMaterial);
    } catch (ATexture.TextureException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception creating texture for RGB camera contents", e);
    }
    getCurrentScene().addChildAt(mBackgroundQuad, 0);

    // Add a directional light in an arbitrary direction.
    DirectionalLight light = new DirectionalLight(1, 0.2, -1);
    light.setColor(1, 1, 1);
    light.setPower(0.8f);
    light.setPosition(3, 2, 4);
    getCurrentScene().addLight(light);
}

/**
 * Update background texture's UV coordinates when device orientation is changed. i.e change
 * between landscape and portrait mode.
 */
public void updateColorCameraTextureUv(int rotation) {
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            mBackgroundQuad.getGeometry().setTextureCoords(textureCoords90);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            mBackgroundQuad.getGeometry().setTextureCoords(textureCoords180);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            mBackgroundQuad.getGeometry().setTextureCoords(textureCoords270);
            break;
        default:
            mBackgroundQuad.getGeometry().setTextureCoords(textureCoords0);
            break;
    }
}
public void updateRenderCameraPose(TangoPoseData cameraPose) {
    float[] rotation = cameraPose.getRotationAsFloats();
    float[] translation = cameraPose.getTranslationAsFloats();
    Quaternion quaternion = new Quaternion(rotation[3], rotation[0], rotation[1], rotation[2]);
    getCurrentCamera().setRotation(quaternion.conjugate());
    getCurrentCamera().setPosition(translation[0], translation[1], translation[2]);
}

/**
 * It returns the ID currently assigned to the texture where the Tango color camera contents
 * should be rendered.
public int getTextureId() {
    return mTangoCameraTexture == null ? -1 : mTangoCameraTexture.getTextureId();
}

/**
 * We need to override this method to mark the camera for re-configuration (set proper
 * projection matrix) since it will be reset by Rajawali on surface changes.
 */
@Override
public void onRenderSurfaceSizeChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    super.onRenderSurfaceSizeChanged(gl, width, height);
    mSceneCameraConfigured = false;
}

public boolean isSceneCameraConfigured() {
    return mSceneCameraConfigured;
}

/**
 * Sets the projection matrix for the scene camera to match the parameters of the color camera
public void setProjectionMatrix(float[] matrixFloats) {
    getCurrentCamera().setProjectionMatrix(new Matrix4(matrixFloats));
}

@Override
public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                             float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep,
                             int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

}
```

}

Comment: Silky, I couldn't understand what do you mean here. Could you try rephrase it a little bit better?

Comment: I want to load ADF as well as I want to place an object(augmented reality) but when I try to do that my screen becomes black and area is not localised

Comment: can you find any error log from logcat?

Comment: No there is no error

Comment: I think couple of things to check. 1. Is TangoPose valid? 2. Is update texture function throwing any error? 3. Is the projection matrix (camera intrinsic) valid?